# How to post to user wall only 1 time when a user allows my app?

Tags: post, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

Currently my app posts to the users wall every time they access the app. I only want it to post to the wall one time when they first authorize the app. Then every time they access it afterward it only updates the news feed status.

here is my current code:

```
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $vars = array(
      'message' => "Message goes here",
      'picture' => "image",
      'link' => "link here",
      'name' => "Name here",
      'caption' => "Caption here"
    );
    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $vars);

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=> $app_url));
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
   echo     "top.location.href = '{$loginUrl}';";
   echo "</script>";
}
```

What do I need to change in order to make that happen?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "only updates the news feed status."?  Updating the feed **will** create a new post.  A status update is the same as any other post on a wall - Only its by that user and usually doesn't contain any links.

Comment: Example of what I mean. I have the scrabble app, but when I use the app, it doesn't post to my wall, it shows up in the news feed and on my activity log saying I played scrabble and a link to the app.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I slightly altered the formatting of your code sample;  I find that a little bit more effort in the formatting makes it much easier to read later.  Especially in the case of someone else reading your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I created a database to store info and it checks to see if the User ID already exists or not. If it doesn't, then they are placed in the database and a post is made to their wall. If they are in the database, then nothing happens.

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';
require 'dbconnect.php';

// Create our application instance
// (replace this with your appId and secret).
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$secret = "APP_SECRET";
$app_url = "APP_URL";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $secret,
  'cookie' => true,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $name = $user_profile['name'];
    $birthday = $user_profile['birthday'];

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=> $app_url));
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
}

//DO NOT EDIT BELOW
$db=mysql_connect($hostname, $dbuser, $pass);
mysql_select_db($database, $db);
//check if user has already signed up before
    $insert = true;
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            //if user id exists, do not insert
            if(( $row['UID'] == $user)){
                $insert = false;
            }
        }

    // if new user, insert user details in your mysql table
    if($insert){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (UID, username, userbirthday) VALUES ('$user','$name','$birthday') ") or die(mysql_error());

    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $vars = array(
            'message' => "message goes here",
            'picture' => "image",
            'link' => "Link here",
            'name' => "Name here",
            'caption' => "Caption here",
);
        $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $vars);
}

?>
```

Comment: Thrilled to see that my post assisted you :/

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices of methods to achieve this behavior.

1. Utilize the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) on the landing page for your users.  This will popup a Facebook window prompting your users to share something on their wall.  This method requires that you implement the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) as well.
2. Utilize the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) and programatically posting a feed story to the `/me/feed` endpoint. (As you have done in the `try-catch` block of your code sample).

With regard to only posting on the users first visit you should store in your database a boolean value.  When you create a new record for the new user in your database you should include a field called something like `first_visit` and populate it with a "true" value.
Then when you detect a returning user (that means he is already in your database) you can check to see that the `first_visit` field is set to "false".  Then your post via the PHP SDK can be the result of a conditional expression to test the `first_visit` value :

```
...
...
if ($first_visit == 'true'){
  $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $vars);
}
```

---

**An additional solution** (not requiring a database) could be something similar to this :

When you so cunningly generate the login URL with the `$facebook->getLoginUrl()` method for your un-authorized users, you can add a temporary `GET` parameter to the `redirect_uri` parameter.  Something like :

```
$redirect_uri = 'https://apps.facebook.com/waffle-ville?new_user=true';
```

Then your conditional expression for posting to the users wall would look something like this :

```
...
...
if ($_GET['new_user'] == 'true'){
  $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $vars);
}
```

Don't forget to redirect the user back to the original URL after you have made the post :

```
var app_url = "https://apps.facebook.com/waffle-ville";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo     "top.location.href = app_url;";
echo "</script>";
```

The redirect is also possible with PHP :

```
$app_url = "https://apps.facebook.com/waffle-ville";
header("Location: {$app_url}");
```

---

[IMO](http://ragegenerator.com/images/ragebuilder-faces/Neutral/37.png) - Posting to a users wall automagically is a little bit annoying.  There is a parameter in your application settings that is called `Social Discovery`.  When this is set to "enabled" a story is automagically created as soon as a user installs your application.  I recommend leaving posting to a users wall as an optional user initiated action.

Comment: The news feed issue aside, I still don't know how to get my app not to post to the user wall every time they use it. I only want the initial wall post when they authorize the app. I'm not sure how to edit my current code to do that??